# Navigation does not appear Xcode 8.1 iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar

Navigation bar does not appear after login button pressed when it moves to Home view controller and I have setup my storyboard and put all thing well but I think i am stuck at this point in code.

**Actually there is no segue but coding instead so How I do navigation working?**

**Code I used to perform Navigation**

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
 self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: Diagram of the application page flow]

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {

        //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {

                //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                print("You have successfully logged in")

                //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful


                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigation Controller have an option to show navigation bar. Check that its checked or not.

Comment: I have updated the question and navigation bar is checked enabled

Comment: You may see the image

Comment: Oh, Login have Navigation bar. Please let me know which is your home screen?

Comment: last line middle one is home

Comment: Ok, Not able to see in picture Which segue you are using between login view controller and Home view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
 self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With this Code:

```
 let vc : YourViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")as! YorViewController
 let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
 self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You are just trying to present the view controller with out Navigation. Give it Navigation programmatically then it will show Navigation bar.

Comment: Thankyousomuchhhhhhhhhh <3

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation so i cant vote :( but I will once i got above 15+ reputation thanx again :)

Comment: Voted dear!_<3!

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using navigationController? If so, should it be `pushViewController` rather than `present`?

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```